# How to Disable Drag-and-Drop Zooming or Set a Minimum Interval in React ECharts for a Line Chart?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

I've been using React ECharts for a line chart, and I'm having trouble with zooming in on the data. I've managed to set a specific interval on the x-axis, but it changes when I try to drag and drop the zoom chart. How can I disable the ability to drag and drop or set a minimum interval for the zoom?

POC Video : [click](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jEbE66VHLNZvlzuMNNx3uozB-LAiivg5/view?usp=sharing)

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import EChartsReact from 'echarts-for-react';
import axios from 'axios';
import daata from './data';
function DataReliabilityTest() {


    const [option, setOption] = useState({});
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    var zoomChartContainer = document.getElementById('your-zoom-chart-container'); // Replace with the actual ID or class of your zoom chart container

    if (zoomChartContainer) {
        zoomChartContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
            // Prevent the default behavior of the mouse down event (dragging)
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        if (data && data.length > 0) {
            setOption({
                title: {
                    text: 'Beijing AQI',
                    left: '1%'
                },
                tooltip: {
                    trigger: 'axis'
                },
                grid: {
                    bottom: '25%'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    data: data.map(function (item) {
                        return item[0];
                    }),
                },
                yAxis: {

                },
                dataZoom: [
                    {
                        type: 'inside',
                        startValue: data[0][0],
                        endValue: data[10][0],
                        zoomLock: true, // This property disables drag-and-drop on zooming
                        moveOnMouseMove: false,
                        disableDrag: true,
                        minSpan: 10,
                        className: 'custom-data-zoom',
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'slider',
                        startValue: data[0][0],
                        endValue: data[10][0],
                        zoomLock: true, // This property disables drag-and-drop on zooming
                        moveOnMouseMove: false,
                        disableDrag: true,
                        minSpan: 10,
                        className: 'custom-data-zoom',
                    },
                ],
                series: [
                    {
                        name: 'Pass',
                        type: 'line',
                        smooth: true,
                        emphasis: {
                            focus: 'series'
                        },
                        data: data.map(function (item) {
                            return item[1];
                        }),
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Fail',
                        type: 'line',
                        smooth: true,
                        emphasis: {
                            focus: 'series'
                        },
                        data: data.map(function (item) {
                            return item[2];
                        }),
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'Warning',
                        type: 'line',
                        smooth: true,
                        emphasis: {
                            focus: 'series'
                        },
                        data: data.map(function (item) {
                            return item[3];
                        }),
                    }
                ]
            });
        }
    }, [data])


    function generateDataArray(numDays) {
        const dataArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < numDays; i++) {
            const currentDate = new Date();
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - i); // Subtract i days from the current date
            const randomNumbers = [
                currentDate.toISOString().split('T')[0], // Current date in YYYY-MM-DD format
                Math.floor(Math.random() * 11), // Generate a random integer between 0 and 10
                Math.floor(Math.random() * 11),
                Math.floor(Math.random() * 11),
            ];
            dataArray.push(randomNumbers);
        }

        return dataArray;
    }
    useEffect(() => {
        const numDays = 31;
        const result = generateDataArray(numDays);
        console.log(result);
        setData(result)
    }, [])


    return (
        <div>
            <EChartsReact option={option} style={{ width: "100%" }} />
        </div>
    )
}

export default DataReliabilityTest
```